# How to make adaptive QGridLayout?

Tags: qt, qtgui

How to make QGridLayout adaptive to the size of the window, so that when I resize it, the amount of cols and rows would change automatically?

Comment: @hyde Oh, I made a mistake - QGridLayout

Comment: If you don't want "flow layout", where items can change rows, but just want more grid layout rows to appear without items "flowing", override resizeEvent and manipulate the layout there based on the new size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds more like a "flow layout", not a grid layout. So no, I don't think `QGridLayout` can do that. And there's no predefined FlowLayout class in qt. BUT: I found this via google:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-flowlayout-example.html

That looks like a semi-official flow-layout implementation.